# My app icon removes from sidebar

Tags: spotify

How I do make my app icon last in the sidebar when shut down spotify? Its is there on startup but are automatically removed when the program initializes.

Answer (score 2):

Which local apps are pinned to the sidebar aren't stored across restarts of the Spotify client. Apps from the App Finder are saved, though.

We hope to add this functionality at a later date.